# how to delete dynamic created li by id?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am a beginner in javascript and I have li which is dynamically inserted by the user and is saved in an array of objects, it has its dynamic random id and I want when the user presses the element, it returns the id of the li and compare it with the movie id so I can find the index and then remove it from the array and remove the li. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
let n;

function deleteFilm() {

    const len = listRoot.children.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        const element = listRoot.children[i]; // listRoot is ul 
        element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const idToRemove = +element.id;
            index = movies.map((object) => object.movieId).indexOf(idToRemove);
            console.log(index);
            n = index;
        });
    }
    console.log(n);

    movies.splice(n, 1);
    listRoot.children[n].remove();
    if (movies[0] === undefined) {
        entryText.style.display = 'block';
    }



    deleteModal.classList.remove('visible');
    blackDrop.classList.remove('visible');


}

acceptButton.addEventListener('click', deleteFilm);
```

Comment: Why would you assign all over again click events on some acceptButton (whatever that is) click? Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assign all over again clicks (specially not inside a for loop).
Your basic logic could be simplified to this couple of lines:

```js
const movies = [
  {id:123, title:"Lorem"},
  {id:456, title:"Ipsum"},
  {id:789, title:"Dolor"},
];

// Retrieve a movie from array by its ID
const getMovie = (id) => movies.find(mov => mov.id === id);

// Remove a movie Object from array
const deleteMovie = (id) => movies.splice(movies.indexOf(getMovie(id)), 1);

// Task:
const movieId = 456; // The movie ID to delete
deleteMovie(movieId);
console.log(movies); // Test
```

Then, to delete elements from the DOM, knowing the ID was  i.e: `456` all you need is to target the elements that have the `data-movieid="456"` like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`[data-movieid="${movieId}"]`).forEach(el => el.remove());
```

Example:

```js
// Utility functions:
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const ELS = (sel, parent) => (parent || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const EL = (sel, parent) => (parent || document).querySelector(sel);


// Task:
const getMovie = (id) => movies.find(mov => mov.id === id);
const deleteMovie = (id) => movies.splice(movies.indexOf(getMovie(id)), 1);
const createMovie = (movie) => {
  const EL_li = ELNew("li", {
    className: "list-item movie",
    textContent: movie.title,
    onclick() {
      deleteMovie(movie.id);
      EL_li.remove();
      ELS(`[data-movieid="${movie.id}"]`).forEach(el => el.remove());
    }
  });
  EL("#movies").append(EL_li);
};

const movies = [
  {id:123, title:"Lorem"},
  {id:456, title:"Ipsum"},
  {id:789, title:"Dolor"},
];

movies.forEach(createMovie);
```

```html
Click to delete a movie:
<ul id="movies" class="list"></ul>

<div data-movieid="456">If you click on Ipsum I will be removed too!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko. It works now

Comment: @MohamedMahgoob you're very welcome!

Comment: @MohamedMahgoob please accept the answer. As @ RokoCBuligan is Correct.